# CSS - Error when combining with Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

Given following snippet in a view:

```
<style type="text/css">
input[type=text]  {
   width: <%: Model.CmsConfiguration.cms_form_width %>px;
}
</style>
```

Now, that works so far. But visual studio shows now a nasty error within this view like `Validation (CSS 2.1): '<%:' is not a valid value for the 'width' property.`. Is there a way to get rid of this?

Thx for any tipps
sl3dg3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing **<%:** at **<% =**

```
<style type="text/css">
  input[type=text]  
  {
     width: <%= Model.CmsConfiguration.cms_form_width %>px;
  }
</style>
```

works well

Answer (score 1):

You are probably better off using a `Generic Handler` that produces the dynamic CSS as you want.

Have a look here:

http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/ASP/Generic_Handlers_%28ASHX_Files%29.html

The handler produces a `select` which is not such a good idea, but to have it produce CSS seems like a perfectly valid thing to do. The example is merely to demonstrate the use of the `Generic Handler`.

Here is something that might do what you are after:

```
using System.Web;
public class CustomFormHandler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/css";
        context.Response.Write("input[type=text]  { "};
        context.Response.Write(" width: " + Model.CmsConfiguration.cms_form_width + "px;");
        context.Response.Write("}"};
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks interesting - but maybe little bit of overhead in my small context?